# PWA NextJs Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm using next13 app based router
I have this code in my `app/layout.tsx`

```
"use client";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function RootLayout({

  children,

}: {

  children: React.ReactNode;

}) {

  useEffect(() => {

    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {

      navigator.serviceWorker.register("/pwa/s.js")

        .then((registration) => {

          console.log("Service worker registered:", registration);

        })

        .catch((error) => {

          console.log("Failed to register service worker:", error);

        });

    }

  }, []);

  return (

    <html lang="en">

      <head>

        <title>Hello</title>

        <meta name="description" content="a simple pwa app" />

        <link rel="manifest" href="/pwa/manifest.webmanifest" />

        {/* Rest of the code remains unchanged */}

      </head>

      <body>{children}</body>

    </html>

  );

}
```

But it gives erorr service worker not registered DOMException {code: 11, name: "InvalidStateError", message: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.", INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, …}service worker not registered DOMException {code: 11, name: "InvalidStateError", message: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.", INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, …}

And this is the s.js file

```
    const urlsToCache = ["/", ""];
```

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {

event.respondWith(

fetch(event.request)

.catch(error => {

return caches.match(event.request) ;

})

);

});



self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {

event.waitUntil(async () => {

const cache = await caches.open("pwa-assets");

return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);

});

});
```

But it's not working